# Do non-parametric tests depend on homoscedastic data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I am finding myself having to perform non-parametric tests, primarily Mann-Whitney tests, on datasets which are not normally distributed.

I notice that the datasets are not homoscedastic - do these non-parametric tests, such as Mann-Whitney tests, require homoscedastic data?

Comment: If you do a 2-sample Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon (signed rank test) for the purpose of determining whether two samples have the same median, then the two samples should be of the same shape (possibly differing by a shift in location). 'Same shape' implies 'same dispersion'. If the two samples have different dispersions (variances), then the M-M-W can be interpreted as a test whether one sample 'stochastically dominates' the other (tends to have consistently larger values than the other). But with heteroscedasticity it is not appropriate to talk just in terms of different variances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple shift.** Consider two non-normal samples of the same shape, but with different medians. [Sampling and computations in R.]

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rgamma(50, 5, 0.1)
y = rgamma(70, 5, 0.1) + 10
summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.48   35.56   48.47   49.92   57.80  161.96 
[1] 50          # sample size
[1] 23.32434    # sample SD

summary(y); length(y); sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  22.84   39.90   56.45   60.10   66.46  173.68 
[1] 70
[1] 28.04877

stripchart(list(x,y), ylim = c(.5,2.5), pch=20)
```

[image]

The stripchart illustrates and the test confirms at the 5% level
that the two samples have different locations. So we can say
that the median 48.44 of Sample `x` is significantly different from
the median 56.45 of sample `y`.

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 1345, p-value = 0.0313
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

**Different shapes.** Although the Wilcoxon signed rank test was originally intended to test for a shift in location, resulting in a difference in medians, it can also be used to detect if one distribution 'dominates' another (tends to give larger values).

Consider the following two samples from beta distributions of
different shapes. Medians are obviously different and variances
are essentially the same.

```
set.seed(2222)
y1 = rbeta(100, 2, 5)l  y2 = rbeta(100, 5,2)
median(y1); median(y2)
[1] 0.2749052
[1] 0.7259123
sd(y1); sd(y2)
[1] 0.1785754
[1] 0.1538957
```

Boxplots show that one distribution is right-skewed (bottom)
and the other is left-skewed. Medians are different. Notches in the sides of the boxes show nonparametric confidence intervals
calibrated so that if two of them don't overlap (as here) then the medians
may be significantly different.

```
 boxplot(y1,y2, notch=T, horizontal=T, 
         col=c("wheat","skyblue2", pch=19))
```

[image]

The Wilcoxon signed rank test finds a significant difference between
the population distribution from which the samples were drawn (P-value near 0), but
the difference is not so simple as recognizing that the medians differ. [The output in R always mentions 'location shift' as the
alternative hypothesis, but sometimes one needs to think carefully about the reason for rejection when the P-value is small.]

```
wilcox.test(y1,y2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  y1 and y2
W = 581, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Here one could say that the second population 'dominates' the first.
Roughly, this means that the second population tends to have larger values. There are several kinds ('orders') of stochastic dominance, and you can google for explanations that match your theoretical level. One method of judging stochastic dominance is that the
empirical CDF (ECDF) plot of the dominating sample falls below and to the right of the ECDF plot of the other.

```
plot(ecdf(y1), col="brown", 
     main="ECDF plots: Blue dominates")
 lines(ecdf(y2), col="blue")
```

[image]

[*Note:* To make the ECDF of a sample of size $n$, sort observations from smallest to largest. The ECDF starts at 0 on the left at $0$ and
jumps up by $1/n$ at each sorted value, reaching $1$ at the right. If there is a tie with $k$ observations at the same value, then the jump at that value is $k/n]$

**Different dispersions.** The Wilcoxon signed rank test may or may not detect a difference between two populations if their samples have markedly different variances. Below the one sample (larger median) clearly dominates the other and the Wilcoxon test rejects.

```
set.seed(111)
x1 = runif(100, 2,3)
x2 = runif(100, 2,3.5)
median(x1); median(x2)
[1] 2.468052
[1] 2.845346
sd(x1);  sd(x2)
[1] 0.2757188
[1] 0.44725

boxplot(x1,s2, notch=T, horizontal=T, 
        col=c("wheat","skyblue2"), pch=19))
```

[image]

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 3067, p-value = 2.337e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

plot(ecdf(x2), col="blue", 
     main="ECDF plots: Blue dominates")
 lines(ecdf(x1), col="brown")
```

[image]

However, if the two populations were $\mathsf{Beta}(2,2)$ and
$\mathsf{Beta}(7,7),$ then one would not expect a two-sample Wilcoxon test to reject. Both distributions have median $\eta =1/2,$ so
sample medians should not be significantly different.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
curve(dbeta(x, 2,2), 0, 1, col="brown", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="W1", 
      main="Density of BETA(2,2)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
curve(dbeta(x, 7,7), 0, 1, col="blue", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="W1", 
      main="Density of BETA(7,7)")
abline(h=0, col="green2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

For the samples below from these two distributions, sample medians are about the same and sample interquartile ranges (IQRs) differ considerably (about 0.26 and 0.19, respectively).

```
set.seed(1228)
w1 = rbeta(100, 2,2);  w2 = rbeta(100, 7,7)
median(w1); median(w2)
[1] 0.5360535
[1] 0.4734114
IQR(w1); IQR(w2)
[1] 0.2640769
[1] 0.192385
boxplot(w1,w2, notch=T, horizontal=T, 
        col=c("wheat","skyblue2"), pch=19)
```

[image]

The P-value of the Wilcoxon test is 0,1136 (not significant at 5%).

```
w = c(w1,w2)
g = rep(1:2, each=100)
wilcox.test(w~g)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  w by g
W = 5648, p-value = 0.1136
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If the main issue is whether one population is more disperse than
another, then a nonparametric test of *dispersion* would be more
appropriate than a Wilcoxon signed rank test, which is a test of *location.*

One possible test whether the two samples have significantly
different dispersions is a *permutation test* using the ratio of
the two sample IQRs as the metric. The observed value of this metric for our two samples is $1.373.$ For the permutation test, we randomly permute the 200 observations between the two groups (100 in each) and
compute the IQR-ratio again. After many iterations we get a
good idea of the permutation distribution of the IQR ratio under the null
hypothesis that the the two populations are equally disperse.

```
rto.obs = IQR(w1)/IQR(w2);  rto.obs
[1] 1.372648
set.seed(33)
m = 10^4;  rto.prm = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 w.prm = sample(w)
 rto.prm[i] = IQR(w.prm[g==1])/IQR(w.prm[g==2])}
mean(rto.prm > rto.obs)
[1] 0.0244
```

The ratios from permutation are seldom as large as the observed
ratio. So a *one-sided* test that the first sample is more
disperse than the second rejects the null hypothesis at the the 3% level of significance.

```
hdr="Permutation Distribution of IQR Ratios"
hist(rto.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
abline(v = rto.obs, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

*Reference:* One elementary paper on permutation tests is [Eudey (2010)](http://jse.amstat.org/v18n1/eudey.pdf).

Comment: It seems to me your comment answers the question but the answer does not.

Comment: @RichardHardy. To clarify: I considered my Ans to be a continuation of my very long Comment for the case where there is a true shift  (even if slightly different SDs).  Was going to illustrate different shapes, but got acceptance and upvote before I got to that, so I figured OP is mainly interested is the pure shift case. [See here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502584/appropriate-statistical-test/502595#502595) for case with different shapes.

Comment: I see. I just thought the question was about heteroskedasticity but the answer did not discuss that. And just now I realized in addition that heteroskedasticity was probably meant across samples rather than within, an unsual use of the term.

Comment: @RichardHardy.  Thanks. // Anyhow, it's probably best if I add parts to show 2 samples with obviously different variances and two with obviously different shapes. // Increasingly often, it seems I'm getting comments and votes on Answers from several years ago, so it might not hurt to give the full story.

Comment: I was interested in both cases @BruceET, but your answer was helpful to me in clearing my misunderstandings and allowing me to understand both in turn. I may have accepted the answer prematurely for the question, but I believe I realise now that my initial question wasn't really what I needed to know in the first place.

Comment: Upvotes are always appreciated ('premature' or not). Mainly just happy your key issue was settled. Added some additional examples to my Answer; look at them if interested. // Happy Holidays!

Comment: The R Wilcoxon test function above seems to have a null hypothesis that the distributions are equal and an alternative hypothesis that the location shift is non-zero. Is this standard, or do other software implement an alternative hypothesis of the shift is non-zero and potentially the shape or variance is different also?

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarity and depth of your answer+edits, and a happy holidays to you too :).

Comment: @SingleMalt: Here's my opinion: Traditional test is for two samples of same shape. Null is that locations are the same; alternate is shift. As originally conceived this amounted to equal medians vs unequal. // Current views recognize that the effect of looking at rank sums is to test whether populations are same vs.one 'stochastically dominates' the other (with various definitions of 'dominate'}. Alternative is _not_ 'different shapes', unless that amounts to 'dominiation'. Alternative is certainly not different dispersions (measured by variance or otherwise). Other opinions differ somewhat.

Comment: @BruceET that opinion makes a lot of sense. Stochastic dominance is probably under-utilised information content from this test (either evidence for or against). Statistical software should give more information in the help files or interactively, especially since statistics is inherently nuanced.