# Appropriate statistical test

Tags: statistical-significance

I have two sets of data, each having sets of unsigned integers in [0,1,2]. Floating point numbers are not possible.

I have thought to use Welch's t-test, but I don't think that this data is normally distributed, as it's only [0,1,2].

I have heard of parametric tests, and thought of binomial tests (obviously binomial is wrong since I can have `2`) but these tests don't seem correct.

Internet searches have only confused me more.

What can of statistical significance test can deal with groups of unsigned integers like this?

Comment: Can you explain what statistic you want to test for significance?  What is the size of each data set?

Comment: What do the integers mean? Are they counts of some kind? Are they qualitative levels like bad/neutral/good that you’ve encoded with numbers?

Comment: @Dave the integers signify genetic allele counts

Comment: @PeterO. I just need to test to see if the groups are significantly different from one another

Answer (score 0):

(1) Maybe the issue is whether categories `1`,`2`,`3` occur in different
proportions in the two samples. This is somewhat like the difference between two binomial proportions, but for three categories instead of two.

```
set.seed(2020)
a = sample(1:3, 100, rep=T, p=c(1,1,2)/4)
b = sample(1:3,  70, rep=T, p=c(2,1,1)/4)
A=tabulate(a);  B = tabulate(b)
TBL = rbind(A,B); TBL
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
A   22   28   50
B   29   17   24
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 7.7315, df = 2, p-value = 0.02095
```

A standard chi-squared test for homogeneity of the two
samples finds a significant difference at the 3% level.

(2) Maybe `1`, `2`, `3` are numerical or ordinal and you want
to see if one distribution 'dominates' the other.

```
summary(a);  length(a);  sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    2.00    2.50    2.28    3.00    3.00 
[1] 100           # sample size
[1] 0.8050347     # sample SD
summary(b);  length(b);  sd(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   2.000   1.929   3.000   3.000 
[1] 70
[1] 0.8734643
```

[Note: Sample mean and SD are appropriate for numerical data, not for ordinal categorical data.]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
cutp = .5:3.5
 hist(a, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 hist(b, prob=T, br=cutp, col="wheat")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 4269, p-value = 0.009168
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

The test finds a significant difference between the samples at the 1% level.

Because the two samples are not of the same shape (skewed in opposite directions), it may not be not appropriate to say that significantly different medians indicate a simple shift of the location of a population.

However,
empirical CDF (ECDF) plots show that A the dominates B. The ECDF
of A (blue) is to the right and below the ECDF of B (brown),
where there is a difference. [Perhaps more simply in this example: A has proportionately more `3`s and and B has proportionately more `1`s.]

```
plot(ecdf(a), col="blue", lty="dashed", lwd=2, 
     main="ECDF Plots of A (blue) and B")
 lines(ecdf(b), col="brown")
```

[image]

If neither of these scenarios is what you had in mind, maybe you can edit your question to say explicitly why not.